# When building AOSP, how to prevent ADB access to services.jar?

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I'm building a custom Android 10 firmware.
I want to prevent the user of the device from being able to copy the firmware code from the device via ADB.

It's a USER build variant.

The user must have ADB access and can't limit it to specific commands.

Currently to get the code he could just do, for example:

```
adb pull /system/framework/services.jar
```

How can I modify AOSP to limit this access? Preferably l would like to prevent access to any other way to get the code from a running device.

Note:

- I know obfuscation is an option, rather have a stronger prevention.
- The user is prevented from going into bootloader mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict shell process to which all partitions it can get access to. This can be achieved by making the changes in SELinux policy.

Reference:
https://source.android.com/security/selinux/customize